# Switching foreign key in hibernate is not working

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

**TLDR;**

I'm using spring boot and jpa.

I want to switch the foreign key of an object, in this case just switching the category of a vehicle.

But when i try to do that hibernate interprets it as if i'm trying to change the primary key of the category object instead of just switching the foreign key and I get this error

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException:identifier of an instance of abc.package.mode.Category was altered from 1 to 2
```

---

I have an entity Category which i'm using only for categorizing vehicle entity object.

```
@Entity
public class Category {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String name;
}
```

Here is the Vehicle class which needs to be categorized.

```
@Entity
public class Vehicle {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator="dish_seq")
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Integer price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.DETACH)
    private Category category;

}
```

Lets say there's 3 categories,

1. 'Sedan'
2. 'Convertible'
3. 'Hatchback'

If i have a car object,
Nissan-PT76, $30000, category: [id:1, name:Sedan]

When i try to change category manually to [id:2, name:Convertible] and persist it, i get

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException:identifier of an instance of abc.package.mode.Category was altered from 1 to 2
```

I cannot switch from one existing object to another. I have tried to look this up in the internet but i couldn't find the right keywords to search for this kind of relationship in hibernate, or does it not allow this kind of relationship at all?

Answer (score 0):

Add column reference to your Category field in the Vehicle class

```
@JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
```

Comment: Nope, this still doesn't let me change the category of the vehicle